# SQL query fails when username variable is added to array

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I have this array which holds the columns and the data to be inserted into said columns:

```
if($this->_insert(array(
'name'=>$fileName,
'size'=>$fileSize,
'ext'=>$fileExt,
'artist'=>$username
))){
```

It works fine when `artist` is not there, or when `artist` equals a string.
So for example if `artist` equals:

```
$username = $user_data['username'];
```

It does not work. (I have checked if that echos out the correct data and it does)

But if `artist` equals:

```
$username = "test";
```

It will then submit the correct data with the `artist` and everything correct.

This is the _insert function:

```
public function _insert($array)
{
    $this->_database=new UploadDatabase();
    $this->_database->connect();
    $values = array_values($array);
    //format fields string
    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($array));
    //$fields = array("name","size", "path", "ext");
    return $this->_database->insert('audio',$values,$fields);
}
```

To sum up, the username breaks the sql when It is the real username variable but not when its a hard-coded string. The problems been annoying me all day and I've tried countless methods but i am close to giving up!

Comment: It looks like your function is designed for an array, not a string. So it would break if you tried to pass a string..

Comment: are you trying to use a PDO or mysql type ? this will work in case of PDO not in case of mysql.

Comment: @john I know, but if I passed `$username = "test";` for example It will work..

Comment: Is the username an array? I had the same problem and realized that the values were an array. try to debug the username.

Comment: @believe me the username is being pulled from the database depending on if you're logged in and youre user_id, so its not in an array its just a variable

Comment: Did you tried to debug just the username how its looks like when you print it out?

Comment: try a print_r on the array and see add it here.

Comment: $array = array(
'name'=>$fileName,
'size'=>$fileSize,
'ext'=>$fileExt,
'artist'=>$username
);
print_r($array);

Comment: thanks for your help everyone, printed the array and saw the error and got it fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As john stated:

```
$array = array( 'name'=>$fileName, 'size'=>$fileSize, 'ext'=>$fileExt, 'artist'=>$username ); print_r($array);
```

Did the trick.